# Get data from sawtooth address on clientside

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have stored data on sawtooth in protobuf format at an address (address made from public key and transaction family).
Get request was made on 
http://rest-api:8008/state/
to get data in the format

```
{
  "data": "CkIwM2FjNjA3MTUzZmRlMzJhNzhiNDFlMzkxN2QwZDlkZmJmMmM2NjZmOWFhZGMzMWRiNTNjODZhNzFkNDMyNmZkNGUSBnNlbGxlchoROTc4LTAtNTc2LTUyMzk1LTAiETgxOS02OTAtNzk4Nng1MTE5Kg0xLTk4MTAtMTE0NS01",
  "head":   "bea2911b4d84b897300fc4a9eb6b56b7ddc59c88c115dab6c09935d658b57cf229b538a3cb3d407647211c8847e46db07f9cff65af2835dfc7732be9b443fae3",
  "link": "http://192.168.1.13:8008/state/318c9fa678220444fb9b209a57c849320a7f61c984e5b8a6a56880030728bdb530a5d0?head=bea2911b4d84b7c7300fc4a9eb6b56b7ddc59c88c115dab6c09935d658b57cf229b538a3cb3d407647211c8847e46db07f9cff65af2835dfc7732be9b443fae3"
```

}

I posted Account data on the sawtooth-rest-api, if the details are correct(checked by processor), Account with additional "Public Key" is inserted onto the blockchain. This is the account protobuf class, which was serialized before it was inserted onto the blockchain.

```
message Account {
  string public_key = 1;
  string user_type = 2;
  string adhaar_number = 3;
  string phone_number = 4;
  string pan_card_number = 5;
}
 transaction = Account()
 transaction.ParseFromString( base64.b64decode(data.encode()))

 THat just gave a number 129.
```

Update:
The account data serialization output is 
        b'\nB033c10fa02a3b602f008e7837a48d4492f5105417111404c4404b49f51222d30c1\x12$60405711-dd32-47c1-a914-3e19ee5177b1\x1a\x06seller"
\x11978-1-61207-456-6*\x10+64(0)19727879362\r0-609-80129-5'

when I base64 encoded it, it gives exactly the same string which i got from sawtooth api under the data key.
but somehow transaction.ParseFromString gives just an integer of 3 digits, Couldnt get the account back.

Sorry I figured this out:
After

```
account=transaction.ParseFromString(<serializedBytes>)
```

The account details can be accessed like normal class variables.

```
account.public_key 
account.adhaar_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you retrieve data vis-a-vis the REST API `/state/xxxx` or `/state?address=xxxx.`

When data is put on the chain in a TransactionProcessor via `setState` or similar call, it does a base64 encoding first.

You will need to do a base64 decode and then `ParseFromString` on that result.

Comment: transaction.ParseFromString( base64.b64decode("CkIwM2FjNjA3MTUzZmRlMzJhNzhiNDFlMzkxN2QwZDlkZmJmMmM2NjZmOWFhZGMzMWRiNTNjODZhNzFkNDMyNmZkNGUSBnNlbGxlchoROTc4LTAtNTc2LTUyMzk1LTAiETgxOS02OTAtNzk4Nng1MTE5Kg0xLTk4MTAtMTE0NS01".encode()))

That gave me just a number 129.

Comment: May be my knowledge of protobuf was limited. Thanks Frank C.

Comment: I assume you dropped the `.encode()` off the tail of the string?

Comment: yes, because it was already in bytes. Is there any email trail where i can ask more sawtooth related questions like whats stopping us to read other transaction family data?

Comment: If you go to the docs: https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/ and select whatever release you are working on there is a `Community` topic which lists all the ways to get help.

Comment: Just because you can decode and then deserialize for protobuf doesn't mean you can read all other family data. For example, in our TP we encrypt the data and you won't get very far. It's up to the application to privatize the data.